# Correct way to customize modules?

Tags: 7

When making changes to files in sites/all/modules/moduleidownloaded where should the changes be stored? I know you shouldn't edit the core module files for risk of updates etc. So where should I put customized module files such as templates and styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two folder `contrib` and `custom` inside `sites/all/modules`. Drupal is able to look up any folders inside `sites/all/modules` to discover the modules.

If it is multiple site structure, you can do the same in `sites/[site_name]/modules`

For the custom templates and styles, if you means the theme one, you can place the theme in `sites/all/themes/custom`, otherwise, templates and styles can be placed inside custom module.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for the Drupal community would be to share back your changes as a [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/707484) on an issue you would open in the given project's issue queue. That way we all benefit.

Alternatively, well-written modules are overrideable and you could customize just those things in your custom module. [Overriding templates](https://www.drupal.org/node/173880) is an example of just such a thing.

Comment: My changes are not always beneficial to others. For example changing text etc.

Comment: Then overriding in a custom module, if possible, will be more maintainable for you than editing a contributed module.